# CbsPersist, and other massive files created

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtualbox, permissions

I've never seen anything like this.

I had a drive go bad, and ever since I replaced it, it seems that there are all kinds of permissions errors, to the point where I can't download anything or install anything because I don't have permissions.  I can only do these things by logging in as Administrator, but I am not sure even that is working correctly as some folders are marked as read only and if I deselect that and apply, it doesn't actually get applied.

I had vmware and virtualbox installed when the drive went bad, maybe this is related?

But more importantly, I logged in today and nearly immediately, I have 3 CbsPersist logs that are all each over 7GB. As well, there are always a bunch of new temporary install folders, what look to be like Windows install folders, but all on my new drive, which is more than a little weird.  Inside these folders is what appears to be language packs, with a setup file that only includes this:

```
[Compat]  
CriticalFileList=MpOAv.dll| 
PlatformUpdate=true
```

Which is referencing a windows defender file.  There is also a a setupres.dll in the top level, but most every other folder created is a language folder, although they all only contain a setupres.dll.mui.  Is this maybe windows 10 always downloading?  Basically I get a new install folder every day.

But more importantly I think are these CbsPersist logs.  2 text files over 7gb in size, all created today, something very weird is going on.

Comment: is the question answered?

Answer (score 8):

The CBS Persist logs are created by the `Windows Module Installer service` (TrustedInstaller.exe) and here Windows logs the status of its work related to installing Windows updates and configuring features. The normal log goes to a file `CBS.log`, but to prevent that file from getting too large, Windows splits them into CBS Persist logs and later compresses them into CAB files with makecab.exe.

[image]

If you have no Windows Update failures, where it would help to look at the files, you can stop the `Windows Module Installer service`, go to `C:\Windows\logs\cbs` and delete the files. Windows will recreate them the next time you install updates.